# Name of buffer to only filename instead of path

Tags: vim

I am using the vim-airline plug-in to improve my status line at the bottom of a vim session.

In my vimrc I have,

`let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1`

What this does is, it assigns a tab at the top of each buffer with the file that is open in that buffer.

My problem is that, the text in that tab has the entire path of the file that is open in the buffer. Whereas I only want the name of the file in the tab of the buffer.

For example if I open the file `~/abcd/bcd/cd/d.txt` in a buffer, then the tab for the corresponding buffer has the text `~/a/b/c/d.txt` whereas I would like it to simply be `d.txt`.

Could someone please tell me if there is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Airline's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues). The author is *very* involved, you should ask him directly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add the following to your vimrc:

`let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'`

it takes anything from `:help filename-modifiers`.